# Passing variables using localStorage. JSON.parse doesn't seem to be working

Tags: javascript, json, html, local-storage

I have an input form on one page to collect information that will allow me to generate a heatmap (using the input data) when the user clicks the submit button.

I am using JSON.stringify to setup the localStorage and JSON.parse to retrieve the data in the correct format, but typeof tells me that the numbers are strings and that the array is an object.

Here is the input code:

```
<h1>Heatmap Parameter Setup</h1>


    <p>Maximum Opacity =  <input id="maxO" type="number" name="maxO"
   min="0" max="1" step=".01" value="1.0" ></p>
    <p>Minimum Opacity = <input id="minO" type="number" name="minO"
   min="0" max="1" step=".01" value="0.0"></p>

    <p>Enter <strong>heatmap data</strong> below. </p>
     <p>Data should be in the form: [{x:123, y: 456, value: 98, radius, 85}, {x:... }, { ... }]  </p>
     <p><input id="heatData" type="text" name="heatData" value="[{x: 597, y: 358, value: 25, radius: 33}, {x: 567, y: 422, value: 25, radius: 33}, {x: 552, y: 338, value: 75, radius: 78}, {x: 487, y: 338, value: 25, radius: 33}, {x: 522, y: 365, value: 100, radius: 100}, {x: 452, y: 352, value: 50, radius: 55}, {x: 437, y: 405, value: 0, radius: 10}, {x: 517, y: 388, value: 75, radius: 78}]"></p>

  <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="pageSel()"></p>

<script>      
  function pageSel() {
    var maxOpacity = document.getElementById("maxO").value;
    var minOpacity = document.getElementById("minO").value;
    var heatData = document.getElementById("heatData").value;

    localStorage.setItem("mxO", JSON.stringify(maxOpacity));
    localStorage.setItem("mnO", JSON.stringify(minOpacity));
    localStorage.setItem("htDat", JSON.stringify(heatData));

    alert("Saved: Maximum opacity = " +  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("mxO")) + ", Minimum opacity = " + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("mnO")) + ", Heat Data = " + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("htDat")));
  window.open("test_new3_min.html")
}  

</script>
```

Here is the code for the test window that opens onclick:

```
    <p>Verifying input data</p>


<p id="demo2"></p>
<p id="demo3"></p>
<p id="demo8"></p>

<script>

  var maxOpacity = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("mxO"));
  var minOpacity = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("mnO"));
  var heatData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("htDat"));

  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Maximum Opacity is = " + maxOpacity
  document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = "Minimum Opacity is = "+ minOpacity
  document.getElementById("demo8").innerHTML = "Heat Data is = " + heatData
 alert( "Opacity type is " + typeof maxOpacity + "Heat Data type is " + typeof heatData ) 
</script>
```

Onclick the alert shows me that Maximum Opacity ("mxO") is a number as opposed to a string, and that Heat Data ("htData") is an object. However, when the new window opens and I check the type using typeof, it tells me that Maximum Opacity is a string.

I need to pass the parameters in the correct format to get the heatmap to render. If anybody can point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it! Thnaks!

Answer (score 0):

If maxOpacity and minOpacity are just numbers, why don't you store them as they are

```
 localStorage.setItem("mxO", maxOpacity); 
 localStorage.setItem("mnO", minOpacity);?
```

But if you really wanna use json you can do:

```
 //storing
localStorage.setItem("maxmin", JSON.stringify({max: maxOpacity, min: minOpacity}));
//retrieving
var maxMin = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("maxmin"));
```

Change the format of the data, and don't stringify it:

```
<input type="hidden" id="heatData" value='[{"x": 597, "y": 358, "value": 25, "radius": 33}, {"x": 567, "y": 422, "value": 25, "radius": 33},{"x": 552, "y": 338, "value": 75, "radius": 78},{"x": 487, "y": 338, "value": 25, "radius": 33},{"x": 522, "y": 365, "value": 100, "radius": 100},{"x": 452, "y": 352, "value": 50, "radius": 55},{"x": 437, "y": 405, "value": 0, "radius": 10},{"x": 517, "y": 388, "value": 75, "radius": 78}

//storing
var heatData = document.getElementById("heatData").value;
localStorage.setItem("htDat", heatData);

//retrieving
var heatData2 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("htDat"));
```

Comment: That seems to work for the numbers, thanks! I was under the impression that localStorage converted them to strings so it was necessary to stringify and parse them. I am still having a problem with the heatData array. It is not being recognized as an array in the window that opens onclick. I also have an object (not shown above) that I am trying to pass through. Any thoughts on the code that I need to use to pass the array and object through?

Comment: Don't stringify the data, is already a string, just do:

`localStorage.setItem("htDat", heatData);`

`var heatData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("htDat"));`